# Getting data from ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, selecteditem

I have created a `ListView` in XAML, but I don't know how to get the data of a selected row. Can anyone help me?

Here is my XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" Margin="10,71,10,45" SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Test1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding test1}" Width="400" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Test2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding test2}" Width="120"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Test3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding test3}" Width="100"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do following

1 Setup up data structure : You can do it in code behind or in XAML. Data has to be a collection type, with the collection of a type that has test1/test2/test3 data member.

```
var data = new ObservableCollection<Test>();  
data.Add(new Test {test1="abc", test2="abc2", test3="abc3"});  
data.Add(new Test {test1="bc", test2="bc2", test3="bc3"});  
data.Add(new Test {test1="c", test2="c2", test3="c3"}); 

Data = data
```

---

```
public ObservableCollection<Test> Data {get;set;}
```

Expose data through property

2 You need to assign collection (setup in step 1) to DataContext of ListView. (preferable in XAML, but in can be done in codebehind)

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" DataContext={Binding Data} Margin="10,71,10,45" SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged" >
```

3 You also need to associate View Model class (containing `Data`) to view

```
<Application
    x:Class="BuildAssistantUI.App"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MainViewModel"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
    >

    <Application.Resources>
        <local:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel" />
    </Application.Resources>


 <Window DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}" >
```

Once you have done above steps, you should see data in the `ListView`.

---

Regarding how to access property from object with anonymous type, this is done through Reflection.

Following is an example

```
object item = new {test1="test1a", test2="test2a", test3="test3a"};
var propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty("test1"); // propertyInfo for test1
var test1Value = propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i know how to add the data. I need to know how i can get the data of a selected row by code

Comment: I think i misread the question. You can use [ListView.SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx) property

Comment: With this code i get the complete data of the selected row:  myListView.SelectedItems[0]; How do i get the data of just one column?

Comment: You need to cast it.
`((Test)myListView.SelectedItems[0]).test1`

Comment: And what class i have to use instead of Test to cast it? I add the data this way: myListView.Items.Add(new { test1 = "", test2= "", test3 = ""});

Comment: You need to define a class, or use reflection

Comment: How would i do it with reflection?

Comment: using [PropertyInfo.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385.aspx), first you need to grab property info (and filter it using property name), then you need to cal PropertyInfo.GetValue on object.

Comment: Edited answer with example of how to retrieve property value.